# Why LinkedIn profile URLs are like `linkedin.com/in/username`?

Tags: design

I am wondering why all LinkedIn profile URLs are of this type `linkedin.com/in/username`. Why not just `linkedin.com/username`? Is there a design reasoning here that I'm missing? (Ex: [linkedin.com/in/williamhgates](https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not everything on LinkedIn is a user.  For example, there is

https://www.linkedin.com/signup/cold-join...

https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/...

Answer (score 2):

While the currently accepted answer is correct, it is pretty sparse on details, so I will elaborate on my own answer.

---

URLs form a logical hierarchy. I actually helped build a social networking site years ago where we did precisely this. We had to add extra code that processed on each request to ensure someone who registered themselves as "about" did not hijack our About Us page, which was available at `domain.com/about`.

Performance and code maintainability implications aside, each segment of a url implies a parent-child relationship between it and the segment that comes before and after it. A semantic relationship exists that is broken if `domain.com/bananas` is a user profile but `domain.com/bananas/recipes` is a listing of recipes that include bananas as an ingredient.

The `in` segment in the url exists to establish that semantic relationship between the top level segment and segments beneath it.

Plus "in" is a short word and fits with their overall branding.

Comment: But GitHub, for instance, does this. Their users can have `github.com/username`, and the website also has things like [github.com/topics](https://github.com/topics) or [github.com/explore](https://github.com/explore). So GitHub's design is not good?

Comment: @iamvegan: I'm not making a judgement about the design decision. Just describing my own experience with this.

Comment: @iamvegan Now I'm curious about users with username "topics" or "explore" on github, how they handle that, e.g., do they not allow these as usernames, or they handle it some other way?

Comment: @auspicious99: Hard to tell. Try signing up as a new user and entering "topics" as a username. GitHub might have a list of reserved usernames like we did for our site.

Comment: @auspicious99 I tried, Github does not allow those usersnames :)

Comment: @iamvegan Cool, so I think this is in harmony with Greg's answer. And we learned something new about github too, not just linkedIn :-)